# How can I use map or a loop for decoding a transformer dataset?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I load a dataset containing columns of text, I want to translate them.

To speed the process I tried to use transformer datasets.

```
model_size = "base"
model_name = f"persiannlp/mt5-{model_size}-parsinlu-translation_en_fa"
tokenizer = MT5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = MT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files=dfname, split='train')

dataset = dataset.map(lambda e: tokenizer(e['input_text'], padding='longest'))


dataset.set_format(type='torch', columns=['input_ids'])

# map for generating translation
#dataset = dataset.map(lambda e: {"trans":model.generate(e['input_ids'])})




dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32)
for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    res = model.generate(input_ids)
    target = tokenizer.batch_decode(res, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

First, I tried to call `model.generate` in another `map` which give this error (commented in code):

```
File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/generation_utils.py", line 378, in _prepare_encoder_decoder_kwargs_for_generation
    model_kwargs["encoder_outputs"]: ModelOutput = encoder(input_ids, return_dict=True, **encoder_kwargs)
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/t5/modeling_t5.py", line 877, in forward
    batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Then I tried to call it in a loop, but it gives the following error for the loop:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prepare_natural.py", line 146, in <module>
    for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1129, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 435, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 475, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 73, in default_collate
    return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 73, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
  File "/home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 55, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [17] at entry 0 and [15] at entry 1
```

Comment: The loop works just fine for me. I think the problem is somewhere else and you should put all the stacktrace

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen I added full stacktrace. It may work for some batches and then outputs the error. By the way, it still seems slow. You can ignore my code and if you know a working fast solution for this (for example using GPU) you may please offer it.

Comment: Have you verified that the padding is working as expect (i.e. check the shape of each dataset item).